# The "Low Quality Posts" queue still displays an obsolete filtering option for questions

Tags: bug, review-queues, low-quality-posts

The Low Quality Posts Review Queue doesn't include any questions - they have all been moved over to Triage for a long time now. However, the filter still lets you choose the Post Type:

[image: Low Quality Posts -> filter -> Post Type: Questions, Answers]

If you only choose *Questions* it says that there are no posts in the queue matching the filter, so it works as expected, but the options are obviously not needed any more.

This is definitely not an issue of any real importance but I just saw it and thought I'd put it out there in case someone wants to fix it real quick.

Comment: Questions still appear in that queue for all other sites on the network. On Stack Overflow, they end up in Triage instead.

Comment: @animuson In that case I'd say it's really not worth the effort and dev time to remove the options just for SO.